# Using an array in conditional summation with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the sql query thats work fine

```
SELECT
    CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE),
    SUM(L.Profit),
    SUM(CASE WHEN (L.Network = 0 OR L.Network = 1) THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN (L.Network != 0 AND L.Network != 1) THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END)

FROM
    [dbo].[Leads] L WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] S WITH (NOLOCK) ON L.TransactionId = S.Id

GROUP BY    
    CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE);
```

I need to make it more generic by using variables instead of hard-coded constants.
I changed the query to:

```
DECLARE @matchNetworks TABLE (id int)
INSERT @matchNetworks(id) VALUES (0),(1)


SELECT
    CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE),
    SUM(L.Profit),
    SUM(CASE WHEN (L.Network in (SELECT ID from @matchNetworks)) THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN (L.Network not in (SELECT ID from @matchNetworks)) THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END)

FROM
    [dbo].[Leads] L WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] S WITH (NOLOCK) ON L.TransactionId = S.Id

GROUP BY    
    CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE);
```

And now i have an error: 
*Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.*

How can I use the predefined array of network ids in my query to avoid an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the comparison to the `FROM` clause using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE),
       SUM(L.Profit),
       SUM(CASE WHEN mn.ID IS NOT NULL THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN mn.ID IS NULL THEN L.Profit ELSE 0 END)    
FROM [dbo].[Leads] L LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Transactions] S 
     ON L.TransactionId = S.Id LEFT JOIN
     @matchNetworks mn
     ON mn.ID = l.Network
GROUP BY CAST(L.CreationUtcDateTime AS DATE);
```